# Linkedin API : Acces to the followed companies, bookmarker jobs, etc of my connections

Tags: api, linkedin-api

I have a problem with the LinkedIn API, I want to retrieve some informations of my connections like :
- bookmarked jobs
- followed companies
- groups to which belong

I ask that because when i want to do :
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/id=XXXXXXXX/job-bookmarks

It returns :

```
{
  "errorCode": 0,
  "message": "Access to job-bookmarks denied",
  "requestId": "Q936KHHD12",
  "status": 403,
  "timestamp": 1391702309565
}
```

In short I want to retrieve all informations of my network/connections that is possible to access.

Do you know how to make that ?

Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can access your connection's information (like their bookmarked jobs) only if they've authorized you to access it. That is a reason your are getting 403 error, which basically means "access denied".

You can read more about user authorization [here](http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication).

Comment: But do you know how to authorized the access?

Comment: The article I've reference in my response has directions on how to acquire authorization. Here is the link again http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication.This authorization and authenication process is typically used by apps to embed LinkedIn data. These apps are typically used by the user who owns the LinkedIn profile, and should not retain that data after used id done using the app.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that only if you have business relationship with LinkedIn. With a basic relationship you can only query basic profile + some of the fields in the Full Profile. You have to ask LinkedIn for that Partnership. Once done, you'll see much more data.